# Autofac Parameterized Instantiation (Custom Factory) vs Resolve class by new

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection, autofac, factory

I have minimized the problem which is: I have a class that returns customer remainig limit. I initilaize this class just in Mvc Controllers(driver project) not in a service or other project.

```
  public class AccountLimit
    {
        private readonly IMoneyService _moneyService;
        private readonly ILimitService _limitService;
        private readonly long _customerId;
        
        public AccountLimit(long customerId,IMoneyService moneyService,ILimitService limitService)
        {
            _moneyService = moneyService;
            _limitService = limitService;
            _customerId = customerId;
        }

        private decimal withdrawalSum { get { return _moneyService.GetTotalWithdrawal(_customerId); } }

        private decimal depositSum { get { return _moneyService.GetTotalDeposit(_customerId); } }

        private decimal depositLimit { get { return _limitService.GetDeposlitLimit(_customerId); } }

        private decimal withDrawalLimit { get { return _limitService.GetwithdrawalLimit(_customerId); } }

        public decimal RemainingDeposit{ get { return depositLimit - depositSum; } }

        public decimal RemainingWithdrawal { get { return withdrawalLimit - withdrawalSum; } }
    }
```

Some controllers just needs `RemaningDeposit`, some of them just needs `RemaningWithdrawal` some of them needs both.
One of them:

```
 [Authorize]
    public class DepositController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IMoneyService _moneyService;
        private readonly ILimitService _limitService;
        private readonly ICustomerService _customerService;

        public DepositController(ICustomerService customerService, IMoneyService moneyService, ILimitService limitService)
        {
            _moneyService = moneyService;
            _limitService = limitService;
            _customerService = customerService;
        }

        public ActionResult GetDepositLimit()
        {
            var customer = _customerService.Find(User.Identity.Name);
            var accountLimit = new AccountLimit(customer.Id,_moneyService,_limitService);
            return View(accountLimit.RemainingDeposit);
        }
    }
```

Then I thought I can use [Parameterized Instantiation](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#parameterized-instantiation-func-x-y-b) which is auto-generated factory by Autofac to pass strongly-typed parameters to the resolution function.

Then my class will have interface  `public class AccountLimit : IAccountLimit`
And my deposit controller will be like this:

```
 [Authorize]
    public class DepositController : Controller
    {
        private readonly Func<long, IAccountLimit> _accountLimit;
        private readonly ICustomerService _customerService;

        public DepositController(ICustomerService customerService, Func<long, IAccountLimit> accountLimit)
        {
            _accountLimit = accountLimit;
            _customerService = customerService;
        }

        public ActionResult GetDepositLimit()
        {
            var customer = _customerService.Find(User.Identity.Name);
            var myAccountLimit = _accountLimit(customer.Id);
            return View(myAccountLimit.RemainingDeposit);
        }
    }
```

Without Parameterized Instantiation I have `new AccountLimit` in my code. My controllers have reference of IMoney and ILimitService.

With Parameterized Instantiation I don't have new in my code I don't have references. But If other developers don't  use Autofac how do they resolve or initilaize this `Func<long, IAccountLimit> _accountLimit` ?

**Question:** I am confused. Is Parameterized Instantiation neccessary here ? I can test my code without it because I can mock customer, money and limit services. I'm just using this class on controllers, so is Parameterized Instantiation overstatement on here ?

*Simply:* Is my first code without Parameterized Instantiation is anti pattern ? Is it ok or should I use Parameterized Instantiation or custom Factory ?

I couldn't find a satisfying answer for these questions by myself. That's why I need your help.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assuming your point is to simplify your controller and make it easier to test**, rather than using parameterized instantiation, I'd probably go with a factory interface and a simple implementation backing it. From a separation of concerns standpoint, I've always felt like a lot of that sort of business logic shouldn't be in a controller anyway.

You started with this constructor:

```
public DepositController(
  ICustomerService customerService,
  IMoneyService moneyService,
  ILimitService limitService)
```

You then refactored in what (rightly) appears to be an effort to remove the controller's dependency on an `IMoneyService` because the controller doesn't really need to know about instantiating `AccountLimit` objects and, after all, the point is to get to the limit part of things. The only reason for the `IMoneyService` was for the `AccountLimit` after all.

```
public DepositController(
  ICustomerService customerService,
  Func<long, IAccountLimit> accountLimit)
```

However, from the snippet it appears you could do the same thing with the `ICustomerService`. What if you had this?

```
public DepositController(Func<string, IAccountLimit> accountLimit)
```

Then you could just pass in the username and get right to the meat of the thing.

```
var limit = _accountLimit(User.Identity.Name);
```

But then you mentioned you want to test things, which is reasonable, and be able to easily mock things in the constructor, so I'd say a simple solution is to refactor to a small provider interface.

```
public interface IUserLimitProvider
{
  IAccountLimit GetLimitForUser(string userName);
}
```

The implementation would be simple enough, taken right from your original controller code.

```
public class UserLimitProvider : IUserLimitProvider
{
  public UserLimitProvider(
    ICustomerService customerService,
    IMoneyService moneyService,
    ILimitService limitService)
  {
    // store these in private fields
  }

  public IAccountLimit GetLimitForUser(string userName)
  {
    var customer = _customerService.Find(userName);
    return new AccountLimit(customer.Id, _moneyService, _limitService);
  }
}
```

I'm guessing you probably want more robust error handling in that factory than what's shown, so having it in a separate method like this rather than a lambda in Autofac registrations will make it easier to test.

**If the whole point of the controller is to *be that provider*** then there's no point in refactoring to the `Func<long, IAccountLimit> accountLimit` version of the constructor in the first place. If the controller's purpose in life is to orchestrate the connection of those three services - `ICustomerService`, `IMoneyService`, and `ILimitService` - then let it take in the dependencies it needs to do so and call it a day.

However, I'm guessing based on my own experience that the controller really isn't where you want to do that, so if it was me... I'd go with the little provider interface.

Bonus: It appears that the whole point of the `ICustomerService` in this case is to map the user name into a user ID. I'm guessing you do that in several places. You may want to consider using `ClaimsPrincipal` and adding a claim to the principal with the user's ID right when they sign in. Then instead of using `User.Identity.Name` You could get the user's ID claim off the principal directly - skip all the lookups - and go right to the services with the appropriate ID. It'd be a decent perf gain, especially if that mapping is always a DB call. Plus it'd remove the need for the `ICustomerService` dependency in a few places, simplifying additional questions you'll encounter around this sort of challenge.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm using controllers as _orchestrate_ which you told for now. So I understand my first code is fine based on this purpose (Am I right ?). Also If you can share documents why services shouldn't be in controller I'll be glad.

Comment: Correct, your first code was fine. I don't have documentation on why services shouldn't be in controllers, it's more about how you look at "single responsibility principle." I feel like the responsibility of controllers is to handle requests coming into the server and hand them off to the appropriate business logic. Controllers do a lot, especially when you consider filters and other such pre/post action things that controllers apply/orchestrate. I like to separate that out. (If this is the answer, please mark it as such.)

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you're going about this in an unneccessarily complex way. The only dependencies I see on AccountLimit are IMoneyService and ILimitService.

CustomerId should be passed into each of the AccountLimit's "properties" (make them methods accepting *CustomerId* as arguments). Nowhere does your AccountLimit mainting state information about CustomerId other than orchestrating between the 2 dependent services, so it doesn't need to store it in it's state.

I'd implement it like:

```
    public class AccountLimit
    {
        private readonly IMoneyService _moneyService;
        private readonly ILimitService _limitService;

        public AccountLimit(IMoneyService moneyService,ILimitService limitService)
        {
            _moneyService = moneyService;
            _limitService = limitService;
        }

        private decimal WithdrawalSum(long customerId) {  return _moneyService.GetTotalWithdrawal(customerId); }

        private decimal WithDrawalLimit(long customerId) {  return _moneyService.withDrawalLimit(customerId); }

        public decimal RemainingWithdrawal(long customerId) {  return withdrawalLimit(customerId) - withdrawalSum(customerId); } 
    }
```

and in your controller:

```
    [Authorize]
    public class DepositController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IAccountLimit _accountLimit;
        private readonly ICustomerService _customerService;

        public DepositController(ICustomerService customerService, IAccountLimit accountLimit)
        {
            _accountLimit = accountLimit;
            _customerService = customerService;
        }

        public ActionResult GetWithdrawalLimit()
        {
            var customer = _customerService.Find(User.Identity.Name);

            return View(_accountLimit.RemainingWithdrawal(customer.Id));
        }
    }
```